# How do I use OSGi services programatically in my Web Application?

Tags: websphere, osgi, websphere-liberty, osgi-bundle

I am building a web application where the customer will be allowed to call their custom OSGi services for validations in the form. For this, I need to continuously monitor a particular folder for any new OSGI bundles being added to it.

I have tried numerous links and tutorials but none of them give a straightforward way for actually doing the task. So far, I have created Hooks - FileAdapterHook, ClassAdapterHook and others. I am not able to understand how to actually install and invoke the services.

I am not using Spring/Hibernate or any other frameworks. Could anyone guide me on how to proceed with utilizing OSGi services.

My tool set:

1. Eclipse IDE
2. IBM Liberty Websphere server
3. JDK 8